# Java mapper/patcher for POJO

Tags: java, mapping

I have a following Java model:

```
public class Product {

    private String name;

    private String description;

    private Date createDate;

    public Product(String name, String description, Date createDate) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.createDate = createDate;
    }

    ...

}
```

I have created an instance of `Product`:

```
Date date = new Date();
Product product = new Product("Test name", "Test description", date);

assertTrue("Test name", product.getName())
assertTrue("Test description", product.getDescription())
assertTrue(date, product.getDate());
```

Also, I have a following `Map`:

```
Map<String, Object> patchMap = new HashMap<>();
patchMap.put("description", "New description");
```

I need to patch existing `product` object with a values from this `patchMap`. Only `description` field should be affected, all other, like `name` and `createDate` should remain the old values.

I need something like this:

```
product = mapper.patch(product, patchMap);

assertTrue("Test name", product.getName())
assertTrue("New description", product.getDescription())
assertTrue(date, product.getDate());
```

Could you please suggest a Java mapping library(and show an example) that can provide a functionality for such kind of patching out of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with Jackson.

Its `ObjectMapper` has a method called `readerForUpdating` that can update an existing structure with new data.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = ...

String json = "{\"description\": \"new description\"}";

mapper.readerForUpdating(objectToUpdate).readValue(json);
```

If you donot want to provide JSON input, it is also possible to skip this step using other methods provided in the Jackson API.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PropertyDescriptor` to get the `setter` method and invoke it, e.g.:

```
Method setter = new PropertyDescriptor("description", Product.class).getWriteMethod();
setter.invoke(product, patchMap.get("description"));
```

This is how it would work with `map`:

```
for(String key : patchMap.keySet()){
    try{
        Method setter = new PropertyDescriptor(key, Product.class).getWriteMethod();
        setter.invoke(product, patchMap.get(key));
    }catch(IntrospectionException e){
        System.out.println("Unable to access method for property " + key + " : " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```